# installed opencv 2.4 but version still shows as 3.3

Tags: python, opencv

i have just installed opencv 2.4 by running the command

`sudo apt-get install -y python-opencv`

but when i run python and check my version of opencv by running

`cv2.__version__`
it still shows as `3.3.0`

Can anyone guide me to change the version of my opencv.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990469/opencv-have-different-version-with-python-module

Comment: `cv2.__file__` will tell you about the location of the OpenCV library used. The solution is probably a symlink.

Comment: Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-opencv=2.4.9
```

or you can use pip

```
pip install opencv-python==2.4.9
```

Comment: Did you remove the last installed opencv by `sudo apt-get remove python-opencv` before install the new one?